# Control Block Processes

Tags: data-structures, architecture

Whenever a process is moved into the waiting state, I understand that the CPU moved to another process. But whenever a process is in waiting state if it is still needing to make a request to another I/O resource does that computation not require processing? Is there i'm assuming a small part of the processor that is dedicated to help computation of the I/O request to move data back and forth?

I hope this question makes sense lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IO operations are actually tasks for peripheral devices to do some work. Usually you set the task by writing data to special areas of memory which belongs to devices. They monitor changes in that small area and start to execute the tasks. So CPU does not need to do anything while the operation is in progress and can switch to another program. When the IO is completed usually an interrupt is triggered. This is a special hardware mechanism which pauses currently executed program in arbitrary place and switches to a special suprogramm, which decides what to do later. There can be another designs, for example device may set special flag somewhere in it's memory region and OS must check it from time to time.

The problem is that these IO are usually quite small, such as send 1 byte over COM port, so CPU has to be interrupted too often. You can't achieve high speed with them. Here is where DMA comes handy. This is a special coprocessor (or part of peripheral device) which has direct access to RAM and can feed big blocks of memory in-to devices. So it can process megabytes of data without interrupting CPU.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I am just reading a book and it just talks about the waiting state and then goes into the ready state. And made it just seem like the waiting state isn't really doing any computation anymore using the processor. I really appreciate the clear up! =]

Comment: I've completely rewritten the answer because I've understood that a more proper explanation can be given.